# Use argv from main.c in another .c file (segmentation error?)

Tags: c, argv

Basically my problem is, that I get a segmentation error when I try to use the passed argv[] from my main.c in another .c file.
I have three files:

main.c

```
...
#include "header.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int number;

if(argv[4] == NULL) {
 number = 512;
 } else {
  number = atoi(argv[4]);
}


 if (strcmp(argv[1], "test") == 0) {
   method1(argv[2], argv[3], number);
 }
...

return 0;
}
```

filewithmethods.c

```
...
#include "header.h"
void method1(char *a[], char *b[], int c) {
 printf("a contains: %s\n", a[0]);
}
...
```

header.h

```
void method1(char *a[], char *b[], int c);
```

When it reaches the printf in filewithmethods.c, I get a segmentation error and I can't access the arguments from my main.c. I'm aware it has something to do with memory allocation and/or pointers, but I still can't figure out how to get it to work, as im very new to C (and programming in general).

Comment: What do you think ```char *a[]``` means? It is an array of ```char pointers```,  whereas you passed a ```char pointer``` to the function.

Comment: `method1` expects an array of char pointers. You pass it a single char pointer when you call it in `main`.

Comment: `method1()` receives pointer to pointer to char. You pass pointer to char. Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: `char *a[]` should be either `char *a` or `char a[]`, not both.

Comment: `main()` should test `argc` before accessing elements of `argv`, to ensure it doesn't access nonexistent arguments.

Comment: There should have been a compiler warning or error that the argument types were incompatible at the callsite. Don't ignore the warnings!